# MySQL entries in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Its a weird problem.

I have a normal `users` table with the first column as the `ID` (PRIMARY, AUTO_INCREMENT).
It works fine. While checking whether my form works or not, I inserted some random data (not through the table, but through the form itself). And then I deleted those entries. Now, obviously the no. of rows of the tables decreased but the `ID` value retained. So at a point the last `ID` in the table was `567` and the no. of rows was `540`. (The gap was `27`)

But, today I rechecked the entries of the table and the gap has increased to `89`. (Last `ID` was 1809 and the no. of rows was `1720`). How is this possible? I never deleted any other entry afterwards when I opened the form for other users.

The structure of my table `USERS`:

```
ID-->PRIMARY,A_I
EMAIL-->VARCHAR(60),UNIQUE
NAME-->VARCHAR(60)
```

After a user registers, he/she is notified about his/her `ID` through a mail on the chosen email id.

While applying to reserve seats for events on another form, a user has to enter the IDs of his/her team members. I check the ID entered in `USERS` table, retrieve the results from there and add it to another table, say `EVENTS`. The php code is of the form:

```
   $members=array containing the IDs entered by the user of his/her team members.
        $result_rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_rows);
                foreach($members as $key=>$value){
                    if ($value>($num_rows+89))
                    $err[]="Error. One of the ID you entered doesnot exist";
}
            }
```

Comment: Is there something that inserts an explicit ID?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Explicit ID? Its the most normal form. You insert your name, email, password in the form. They are added in the database. Thats it. And the `ID` is assigned to each user. No other forms of addition to the database in any way.

Answer (score 0):

How can users be deleted from your system?

Auto_increment fields do just that -- for each new row, they +1.  Doesn't matter if you delete -- they just increment accordingly.

So if you add John Doe, then Delete that record and readd it, your new ID is 2 -- ID 1 is gone.  And then you add Jane Doe, delete it, readd it, new Id is 4, but only 2 records in the table.

So in your case, when ID was 567, 89 user records had to have been deleted to get to 1809.

Alernatively, depending upon your table structure, another possible option would be INSERT IGNORE -- if you try to insert a duplicated user John Doe twice for example, and you have a Unique Key constraint, the id will auto-increment still even though no new record will be added.

Last note -- it really shouldn't matter.  Let the database handle the ID.  If you truly need a 1,2,3,etc. approach, you'll need to build your own.

Comment: Actually, I have another form: `register.php` where the users enter their `ID` and the form checks whether it is valid or not. So I count the no. of rows and put a condition like : `if ($enteredID> ($rows+27))-->false`.
But now and then, I have to change the condition. Recently, I edited it to `if ($enteredID > ($rows+89))-->false`.   I hope you are getting my problem.

Comment: @xan -- why would a user check their ID (number ID value)?  Let the DB handle that field.

Comment: Actually, the form is for event registration. We have assigned all the users IDs of the form `XYZ<ID>`. So, a user registers his team by entering only the IDs. And all the details <names, email, etc.> are automatically added.

Comment: @sgeddes I think xan means he did not delete 89 users but only 27 users.

Comment: @TonyShih: You are right. I deleted the 27 entries I made in the starting. Once the form was open for audience, I stopped even opening/seeing the database or even modifying it in any way.

Comment: @xan do you maintain any database log files?

Comment: @TonyShih: I don't think so. I just know the basic things like accessing the phpMyAdmin etc. If the log files have to be maintained manually, then no. If they are automatically created, then obviously yes.

Comment: @xan -- I have to admit, this sounds extremely confusing.  This is your USERS table?  How are the fields auto-populated unless the user is filling them out?  What do you mean by you have assigned?  There has to be a better approach if I "understood" your situation -- you never want to hard-code values as such.

Comment: @sgeddes:Okay. I have a table `USERS`-->ID,NAME,EMAIL. While registering for the first time, each user gets a message on the email he/she chose with his/her ID.   Now I have another table, `EVENTS`. Users fill the IDs of their team members (in order to get registered as a team). I search the `USERS` table for each ID `entered`, retrieve the results and add it to the `EVENT` table.

Comment: @xan -- that all makes sense -- still not understanding why you hard code values -- user enters name/email -- db generates ID -- emails sends that ID to user -- user enters that ID into the event registration page -- event registration page should just check to make sure that's a valid ID (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = 123).  Where did I get lost :)

Comment: is there any cascading delete happening in the system or internal logic deleting user entry, something such unregister...

Comment: @xan - btw, to get back to your original question, post your table structure -- do you have a unique constraint on the users email or name -- if so, when the user fills out the user registration form, and they enter the same email, the db won't enter it but the id will still be created (INSERT IGNORE) -- that could be causing your missing ids...

Comment: @xan -- I have to head out -- hope you figure out a solution -- I'd be happy to help tomorrow as I think you have a workflow/logic issue unrelated to the missing deleted items.  Best of luck !

Comment: @xan -- you email is unique -- that could be causing your missing Ids most likely -- when the user registers for the first time, if you aren't checking to see if their email is unique prior to the insertion, the id will increment, but the record will not create.  In regards to your 2nd issue, change your php code.  You're just checking if the id is within a range of min and max -- change that to actually see if they exist -- look at using php implode -- then you can have one sql statement that can return basically true or false.  Best of luck -- I'm gone for the day/night!

Comment: @sgeddes: I'm checking the email id during registration. Thanks anyways. I'll try to look into it myself. Will inform you if I achieve something.

Comment: @sgeddes: Just to give you an update:
I don't know why is the gap still increasing(from 88 to 91 in 3 hours). And, I do check if the email exists or not during registration. But instead of checking the condition using `if`, I used `mysql_fetch_assoc`. It worked. No need for me to put a check using IDs now.:)

Comment: @sgeddes: The error was due to this: I was adding the details and after that checking for the unique feature of the email. The email should be checked first for any duplicacy and then the values should be inserted.